# How to Copy CD+Graphics / Karaoke CDs?

Tags: windows-7, burning, compact-disc, karaoke

Is there any good software to copy CD+Graphics (aka Karaoke CDs) for Windows 7?  Preferably free.  I can copy the audio portion just fine, but for some reason I keep looking the karaoke lyrics / graphics portion.  It used to be that a lot of the software supported these specifically, but now I am having a hard time finding any mention of this feature, and the ones I have tried didn't work.

Comment: Nero afaik supports this if you read all subchannel data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tired the [Power CD+G Burner](http://www.powerkaraoke.com/src/prod_powercdgburner.php) by [Power Karaoke](http://www.powerkaraoke.com/)?  The website says it supports Windows Vista so it should work with Windows 7.

Its not free, but they have a trial version.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect any software that does a bitwise copy of the disc should work. If not you could try creating an iso file from something like cdburnerxp and burning that back to a disc.

Answer (score 0):

The open source [cdrdao](http://sourceforge.net/p/cdrdao/) copies disk-at-once on Linux, BSD, MAC OSX, and Windows.  DAO is required to get the subcode graphics.

[cdgtools](http://www.kibosh.org/cdgtools/) takes that and can burn to another CD or rip it apart to mp3 and G.   Play directly off the hard drive via [pykaraoke](http://www.kibosh.org/pykaraoke/).

When CDG is ripped to two case-sensitive files - .BIN and .TOC, the files have-to-have the exact same name except for the filename extension.

Comment: Now, we just need the python modified to rip to HTML5.